# Install VSCode in a specific folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just downloaded the Visual Studio Code App from https://code.visualstudio.com/ and when I tried to install it, it simply just installed it by itself, without the option to change the installation path.

I have an external harddrive, which is where I want the IDE to be placed instead of the Local Harddrive. How can I change this?

Comment: The installer does very little beyond copying the files, it just creates some Explorer context menu shortcuts ("Open with Code").  Otherwise following Chromium conventions and copying itself to c:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.1.0 so it can update itself without you noticing.  Boo.  So high odds that simply moving that folder to the other drive works just fine, put it anywhere and create a shortcut to Code.exe.  If you still want the context menu entry to work then use Regedit and search for "code\app-0.1.0".

Comment: Hans, you should put that in as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Full credit to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) for giving the following working solution as a comment.**

The installer does very little beyond copying the files, it just creates some Explorer context menu shortcuts ("Open with Code"). Otherwise following Chromium conventions and copying itself to c:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.1.0 so it can update itself without you noticing. Boo. So high odds that simply moving that folder to the other drive works just fine, put it anywhere and create a shortcut to Code.exe. If you still want the context menu entry to work then use Regedit and search for "code\app-0.1.0".

Answer (score 11):

On the [VSCode download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) select "System Installer" instead of "User Installer". The System installer will prompt you for the install location.

[image: Screenshot of "System Installer" link]

Comment: This is the best advice I have seen anywhere in a single picture.  Make sure you use the "System Installer" and "Install for All Users" using a system administrator privileged account.  Then enable VSCode to "Run As Administrator" by default.

Comment: This no longer works. The System installer no longer asks for a location. It goes into Program Files now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install to a custom location (and want to keep the settings/extensions/session) follow the instructions to install it in [Portable Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable).

In short:

1. Download the .zip version
2. Create a `/data` directory in the install root