# VSCode PowerShell terminal UnauthorizedAccessException when reading config file

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am getting the following error when launching a PowerShell terminal from VSCode:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: PowerShell has stopped working because of a security issue: Cannot read the configuration file: C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\powershell.config.json ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\powershell.config.json' is denied.
```

I am in a corporate environment with no admin rights but that does not seem to be the issue as I can open that config file with non-elevated processes. Also, I can launch the Powershell terminal outside VS Code fine.

I believe Powershell can't access files in Onedrive, I read somewhere that by disabling Files On-Demand this issue can be solved but I am still getting that error.

Is there a way to change the config file location outside Onedrive? I checked VSCode settings but didn't find any option.

UPDATE: This seems to be actually a permission issue as it is happening when running Powershell outside VSCode too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install VSCode in a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013157/install-vscode-in-a-specific-folder)

Comment: @Scepticalist That doesn't seems to address this specific issue

Comment: It tells you how to install in different location, outside OneDrive, which is what you asked.

Comment: I was asking about the PowerShell config file location but thanks for the help